# Visual Studio Code не компилирует TypeScript в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Пытаюсь скомпилировать в файл .js простой вывод строки в консоль. Для этого прописываю в терминале:

```
tsc "filename".ts
```

Ошибок не выдаёт, файл .js появляется. но он пуст! соответственно при запуске `node "filename".js` ничего в консоль не выводит.
Что я делаю не так? (на всякий случай приложил скрины)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: точка рядом с именем файла показывает, что он не сохранен. Может быть в компилируется пустой файл?

Comment: да, так и есть, забыл сохранить). спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По сути VS code это текстовый редактор немного навороченный.

Попробуйте `tsc example.ts` находясь в директории с файлом предварительно сохранив исходный файл

Comment: именно это он и делает

Comment: да вижу теперь.

Comment: да, что я забыл, так это нажать ctrl + s)
спасибо, что напомнили про сохранение. после idea совсем об этом забываешь